# How do I group by day instead of date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, group-by

ok so i have

```
 >> list = Request.find_all_by_artist("someBand")
=> [#<Request id: 1, artist: "someBand", song: "someSong", venue: "Knebworth - Stevenage, United Kingdom", showdate: "2011-07-01", amount: nil, user_id: 2, created_at: "2011-01-01 18:14:08", updated_at: "2011-01-01 18:14:09".............
```

and then

```
list.group_by(&:created_at).map {|k,v| [k, v.length]}.sort
=> [[Sat, 01 Jan 2011 18:14:08 UTC +00:00, 10], [Sun, 09 Jan 2011 18:34:19 UTC +00:00, 1], [Sun, 09 Jan 2011 18:38:48 UTC +00:00, 1], [Sun, 09 Jan 2011 18:51:10 UTC +00:00, 1], [Sun, 09 Jan 2011 18:52:30 UTC +00:00, 1], [Thu, 10 Feb 2011 02:22:08 UTC +00:00, 1], [Thu, 10 Feb 2011 20:02:20 UTC +00:00, 1]]
```

the problem is I have a few Sun, 09 Jan and a couple for the 10th, instead of one like this

this is what i need

```
=> [[Sat, 01 Jan 2011 18:14:08 UTC +00:00, 10], [Sun, 09 Jan 2011 18:34:19 UTC +00:00, 4], [Thu, 10 Feb 2011 20:02:20 UTC +00:00, 2]]
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`Time` is a quite complex object to group by. Assuming you want to group by the creation date, instead of the full `Time`, start creating a custom method in your model to return the group criteria.

The method should return the creation date, possibly as string.

```
def group_by_criteria
  created_at.to_date.to_s(:db)
end
```

Then, group by that method.

```
list.group_by(&:group_by_criteria).map {|k,v| [k, v.length]}.sort
```

Comment: What's wrong with just 'created_at.to_date' without the to_s ?

Comment: Objects by default compares true when they have the same `object_id`, unless the `eql?` method is customized. Grouping by complex objects might be dangerous because objects with the same value might not be considered the same. Two time instances referencing the same date are considered equal, but this is not true for every kind of objects. Sorting by String or Fixnum is more secure.

Comment: Simone: Using to_s wouldn't be anymore "secure". What if I have two different objects with the same string representation? Same problem occurs.

Comment: I got the same problem, please help me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763144/undefined-method-group-by-day-rails-3-2

Comment: @SimoneCarletti I'm curious what's the `(:db)` doing in `to_s(:db)`? As far as I know `to_s` doesn't take any arguments. Can you clarify please?

Comment: Rails extends `to_s` to accept formatting for dates. You can get more details in the Rails documentation.

Comment: I think this is going to pull all the relevant records and then group in Ruby. That is going to be very slow for a large number of records. It would be much faster to group in the (SQL) DB.

Answer (score 28):

I think this is a much more elegant and simple solution

```
list.group_by{|x| x.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}
```

Comment: nice and clean!

Answer (score 9):

There is a gem for that: [groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate).

Usage (from the docs):

```
User.group_by_day(:created_at).count
# {
#   2013-04-16 00:00:00 UTC => 50,
#   2013-04-17 00:00:00 UTC => 100,
#   2013-04-18 00:00:00 UTC => 34
# }
```

Answer (score 3):

Ipsum's answer is actually good and probably the best:

In Arel:

```
requests = Arel::Table.new(:requests)
query = requests.project("COUNT(*), CAST(requests.created_at AS DATE) as created_at")
query = query.group("CAST (requests.created_at AS DATE)")
Request.find_by_sql(query.to_sql)
```

Comment: This works great, just remove the space after the second CAST, mysql doesn't like that.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `GROUP BY DATE(created_at)` in MySQL

On ruby code you can use like this

```
list.group('DATE(created_at)').map {|k,v| [k, v.length]}.sort
```

Answer (score 0):

Group without extra gems:

```
def self.group_by_day items
   data = items.group_by{|x| x.created_at.to_date}
   chart_data = {}

   data.each do |a,b|
     chart_data.merge!({a => b.count})
   end

   return chart_data
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered [groupdate gem](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) which seems like a good fit for handling this task.

This code example demonstrates how to use it in practice to solve the problem:

```
list.group_by_day(:created_at)
```

The most important part here is that behind the scene it generates SQL, that's much more performant than a plan Ruby code.