# undefined method `group_by_day' - rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I want to make a line-chart of the number of User signups (per day) using **chartkick**, it is a simple one line code but it is giving an error

```
`undefined method `group_by_day' for #<Class:0x00000004b4fbf0>`
```

in my views I have

```
<%= line_chart User.group_by_day(:created_at).count %>
```

error logs:

```
Rendered admin/dashboards/index.html.erb within layouts/application (145.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1018ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `group_by_day' for #<Class:0x00000004b4fbf0>:
  activerecord (3.2.14) lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:55:in `method_missing'
  app/views/admin/dashboards/index.html.erb:38:in `_app_views_admin_dashboards_index_html_erb___3330517857505238097_39214860'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.14) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.14) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To have `group_by_day` supported, you need to bundle another gem: [groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) from the same author of Chartkick.

Comment: thanks a lot, I checked the gem and it was what i was missing.

Comment: but there is something which I don't understand, why cant I access an attribute from another table. For example: <%= pie_chart User.city.group("name").count %>, from this I would like to access the name of the city of the user. Not working, what I'm i doing wrong here?

Comment: @ben I think you mean count the number of users in each city, probably you can try `User.includes(:city).group("city.name").count`

Comment: sure. it seems that User.includes(:city).group("city.name").count is better than User.join(:city).group("city.name").count, since it also includes those users with no cities. thanks

Comment: you can also check this and help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797869/making-a-pie-chart-of-the-user-age-in-rails

Answer (score 2):

I can't see the definition of the `group_by_day` method. This is not a standard method. May be you are referencing `group_by`.

In any case, `group_by` is not defined for the ActiveRecord class. It's defined on `array`.

You first have to fetch the record into an Array. Also, if `created_at` is a method, you need to pass is using the &.

```
User.all.group_by(&:created_at)
```

Also, I'm not sure the `.count` at the end behaves as you may expect. It's counting the groups of the dates (and in case of created_at it will return almost one item for each record because the created_at is really hardly duplicated)

Comment: You are right, I came from a comment a question of mine and I didn't notice the wrong method name. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987392/how-do-i-group-by-day-instead-of-date/4987487 I updated the answer.