# `undefined method `group_by_day' for 10:Fixnum` with Chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I'm trying to make a chart using `Chartkick` and am getting this error: `undefined method 'group_by_day' for 10:Fixnum`.

As recommended by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763144/undefined-method-group-by-day-rails-3-2) SO post, I installed the gem `groupdate`, so that isn't the problem.

My `index` method from my `tasks_controller` is:

```
def index
  @tasks = Task.where(user_id: current_user.id).order("created_at DESC")
end
```

And my `erb` in `tasks#index` is:

```
<%= line_chart @tasks.map { |task|
      {name: task.name, data: task.reps.group_by_day(:created_at)}
   } %>
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Well `task.reps` is a number, not sure how one would group that by day. Probably you need something other than `task.reps`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Each set of reps was `created_at` on a day, so I guess I was hoping it would group based on that.  How would I do it without grouping at all?

Comment: You’re missing what I (and the error) are indicating (unless that error doesn’t occur in your given view code): the value that `task.reps` returns is a number, and numbers can (apparently) not be `grouped_by_day`. There is no “set of reps”, it seems.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, sorry if I'm being obtuse.  So how would I get the chart to render without grouping at all, to simply have a datapoint per task, with `created_on` on the X axis and the integer for `reps` on the Y axis?