# slice each day ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im creating a time line with some columns from a table.
At the moment is the time line just display each column ordered by the "created_at" field.
But i want slice it for each day like this:

```
       TODAY
content -|
         |
         |- content
         |
content -|
         |
      YESTERDAY
         |
         |- content
         |
content -|
```

At the moment am i using this code

```
<ul>
<% @timeline.each do |timeline| %>
    <li>
        <%= timeline.title %>
    </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

I want to do something like the "each_slice(5)" function.
Hope anybody can tell me how to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987392/how-do-i-group-by-day-instead-of-date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group your array with ruby `group_by`:

```
@timeline.group_by { |el| el.created_at.to_date.to_s(:db) }
```

Note: I assume that @timeline already sorted.

Probably, this method will be reusable, so better place it in models like:

```
def self.to_grouped_by_day
  group_by { |el| el.created_at.to_date.to_s(:db) }
end
```

And than call it in the controller.