# How to group and count by day in Rails in Postgres?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

This SO question [How do I group by day instead of date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987392/how-do-i-group-by-day-instead-of-date) shows how to group in Ruby.

This works, but is going to be very slow for a large number of records.
How to do it so that the grouping and counting by `:created_at` by day happens within Postgres?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you haven't an order scope defined, you can use `date()` method from postgres, like this:

```
Post.select("date(created_at) as created_date").group("created_date")
```

And if you do have an order scope:

```
Post.all.except(:order).
     select("date(created_at) as created_date").group("created_date")
```

You will have to define select fields in order to have a custom grouping, so the `select()` part should contain the fields you need your recordset to contain.